# flash video covering JQueryUI model dialog

Tags: jquery, flash

I have a site with a flash SWF on the home page. I have a login dialog that is displayed using the jquery ui modal. The modal dialog is being covered by the SWF movie when it opens. I tried setting the z-index etc but nothing seems to stop the SWF from covering the log in.

Is there any way to force the SWF movie to the background?

The SWF uses src="support/AC_RunActiveContent.js" if that helps isolate the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi use this code in your html and embed

```
<PARAM NAME=wmode VALUE=transparent>
```

find the embed and add this

```
wmode="transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, at least on some browsers, the flash applet will **always** appear above everything else on the page. It's probably best to not assume you can display content over it.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by embedding the SWF in the page with a special tag.

I believe it is `wmode=opaque` and you add this to the embed tag. (You would add a similar param to the object tag.)